# Unable to detect $_SESSION['username'] on index/auth page

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am unable to display $_SESSION['username'] on my index.html/auth.php page after logging in. It's strange because it's able to detect $_SESSION['username'] on other pages after logging in, just not my index/auth page.

EDIT: When logging in correctly, login.php goes to index.html. index.html is then displaying the 'login' button from auth.php, as ' Login '

login.php, where the user will enter the username and password to login and $_SESSION['username'] is created.

```html
<?php session_start(); 
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        // removes backslashes
 $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        //escapes special characters in a string
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
 $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
 //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'
and password='".md5($password)."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            // Redirect user to index.html
     header("Location: ../index.html");
         }else{
 echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
 }
    }else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required  style="text-align: center;"/>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required  style="text-align: center;"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<a href='resetpassword.php'>Forgotten Password?</a>
   <br/><a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html, where the auth.php page is called (the rest of my index.html page is not important to this issue, replaced with 'blah blah blah').
EDIT: My server is configured so that index.html can run php.

```html
<?php session_start(); ?> 
 <?php require('login/auth.php'); ?>
  <?php include('login/checkadmin.php'); ?>
  <?php include('login/getoutages.php'); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
blah blah blah
</html>
```

auth.php, where the database is used and where $_SESSION['username'] is meant to show but doesn't!

```html
<?php session_start();
    ob_end_clean();
   
   if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    ?>
   <table id="signedin">
   <tr>
   <td colspan="5">
     Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="right">
  <a id="logouts" href="login/logout.php">Sign Out</a>
  </td>
  <td align="right"> 
  </td>
  <td align="left">
  <a id="profiles" href="login/profile.php">Profile</a>&nbsp;
  </td>
  </tr>
   </table>
   
   
   <?php } else if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
  
   <div id="notsignedin"><a id="logins" href="/login/login.php">Login</a></div>
   
    <?php } ?>
```

Any information is helpful! Thank you!

EDIT: I have updated my code to run session_start(); before anything else.
Still unable to detect $_SESSION['username'].
EDIT2: Switched $username = $_SESSION['username']; in login.php to $_SESSION['username'] = $username; Still not showing on auth.php

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: `session_start()` must be called before any output.  Can you confirm you are not outputting anything prior to it? including whitespace.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You do not store anything into the `$_SESSION` variable within your shown snippets. Could be useful to store something before attempting to read it.

Comment: And now we need the error log file.

Comment: `index.html` usually does not execute PHP code. Did you configure your server to do so?

Comment: There is unfortunately no error log file, nothing that says anything about headers being sent. I've refreshed and checked both the folder containing login.php & auth.php, and the folder containing index.html.

Comment: I did indeed configure my server so that index.html runs php.

Comment: What is actually happening when giving the correct username and password?

Comment: When logging in correctly, login.php goes to index.html. index.html is then displaying the 'login' button from auth.php, as '<?php } else if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
  
   <div id="notsignedin"><a id="logins" href="/login/login.php">Login</a></div>
   
    <?php } ?>'

Answer (score 0):

You should start the session in every file before anything else

`<?php session_start(); ?>`

At least if you are calling every page separately

Answer (score 0):

You need to call session_start() before checking the issest($_Session['username'])

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `session_start();` before it calls `$_SESSION` variables on that page, therefore `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])` will not be "set" until the session is started, just move it to above in the page, it's good practice to call it in first. I usually put it in my config page along with my DB connection and include it in every page :)

Hope this helps